# How can I retrieve the name of the .msi file being installed?

Tags: variables, installation

In a VS.Net setup project there are variables such as ProductName and TargetDir, but is there a way to use the setup's .msi filename in a registry entry? [ProductName] can be used in the registry view registry entries, but I want to put the .msi filename being used in the registry.

Comment: For Windows installers its not the name of the MSI that is important but the product guid.  Products are installed and uninstalled using a guid:  MsiExec.exe /I{16C8C612-A0DA-4EB9-84E4-121349909436}  The MSI.DLL can be p/invoked to pull products out of the registry, but you would need to know the product name or GUID of the product to pull the product out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the .msi file used to start the installation is stored in [`OriginalDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370562.aspx) property.